# Resize an eqnarray environment

Tags: beamer, equations, resize, scale

I am writing a mathematical model using eqnarray environment in beamer, the problem is that I need it to be smaller, so I tried to use resize it using \scalebox or resizebox but I got error (not familiar with them thoug). Is there an easy way to resize the eqnarray environment ? (Do not want to use the \small, \tiny  to change font size). Below there is a little equation I would  like to apply some resize action. Thanks in advance.

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\begin{eqnarray}    
&& \textbf{TP} ~~\text{Max} \sum_{i \in N\setminus\{4\}} J_{i} z_{i} 
\label{S1}\\
&& \text{st} \nonumber\\
&& \sum_{j \in N} xv_{ij} = z_{i}, ~~\forall i \in N \label{S2}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your objective isn't entirely clear. On the one hand, you say you don't want to use a smaller font size (via an instruction such as `\tiny`, say). On the other hand, you also say that the system of equations needs to be made smaller. What's driving the implied preference for `\resizebox` over using a smaller-than-normal font size?

Answer (score 3):

with use of `mathtools` and `nccmath` you can slightly reduce size of equation (without changing font size):

```
\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagelabels=false}]{beamer}
\usepackage{mathtools, % instead amsmath, provide `\mathclap`
            nccmath,   % for smaller `sum` symbol
            amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
    \begin{align}
& \textbf{TP} ~~\max \medop\sum_{\mathclap{i \in N\setminus\{4\}}} J_{i} z_{i}
\label{S1}\\
& \text{st } 
  \medop\sum_{j \in N} xv_{ij} = z_{i},\ \forall i \in N \label{S2}
    \end{align}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

note: eqnarray is long time deprecated and replaced with math environment from `amsmath`.

[image]

for comparison result with your mwe:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `\resizebox` or `scalebox` unless you're fine with making your document look like an attempt at a ransom note.

To conserve some (vertical) space, don't place the "such that" statement on a separate line, and do place the limits of summation to the right of the summation symbols rather than below and above them; do this by writing `\sum\nolimits`. And, do use LaTeX "operators" such as `\max` for some standard math notation.

Since there seems to be no reason to perform vertical alignment, just use a `gather` environment. A final comment: The `eqnarray` environment is badly deprecated and should be avoided. If you must perform alignment across equations, use the `align` environment (provided by the `amsmath` package).

The following screenshot provides a before-and-after comparison; the first two equations generate your code, and the next two show a space savings of more than a third -- all without having to resort to `\resizebox`-based tricks.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
\hrule
\begin{eqnarray}    
&& \textbf{TP} ~~\text{Max} \sum_{i \in N\setminus\{4\}} J_{i} z_{i} 
\label{S3}\\
&& \text{st} \nonumber\\
&& \sum_{j \in N} xv_{ij} = z_{i}, ~~\forall i \in N \label{S4}
\end{eqnarray}
\hrule
\begin{gather}    
\mathbf{TP}\quad \max \sum\nolimits_{i\in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{4\}} J_{i} z_{i} \label{S1}\\
\text{s.t. }
\sum\nolimits_{j \in N} xv_{ij} = z_{i}\quad \forall i\in \mathbb{N} \label{S2}
\end{gather}
\hrule
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In that context, “s.t.” stands for “subject to”

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for pointing out this issue. I'll apply the fix.